# How to save mediaupload multiple URLs as array meta?

Tags: plugins, block-editor, meta-value

I want to add multiple images to meta. I am able to save single url successfully. I am not sure how to add multiple URLs to meta.

The single image mediaupload works fine. below is the code for it. The multiple mediaupload works fine in the backend editor. I don't know how to save and retrieve(in php) multiple image paths in meta. Can anyone please help or guide me in the right direction?

attributes that save the meta values for a single image.

```
p_mediaURL: {
        type: "string",
        default: "",
        meta: "_duib_p_mediaURL",
        source: "meta",
    },
    p_mediaID: {
        type: "integer",
        default: null,
        meta: "_duib_p_mediaID",
        source: "meta",
        default: "",
    },
```

In edit function:

```
    const onSelectImage = (media) => {
        setAttributes({
            p_mediaURL: media.url,
            p_mediaID: media.id,
            mediaAlt: media.alt,
        });
    };
```

Mediaupload component

```
<MediaUpload
    onSelect={onSelectImage}
    allowedTypes="image"
    value={p_mediaID}
    render={({ open }) => (
    <Button className="is-primary mt-3" onClick={open}>
    Open Media Library
    </Button>
    )}
/>
```

Mediaupload component for multiple images that works in editor.

```
<MediaUpload
    onSelect={(gallery) => {
    props.setAttributes({ gallery});
    }}
    type="image"
    multiple
    value={props.attributes.gallery}
    render={({ open }) => (
    <Button className="button button-large" onClick={open}>
        Select Images
    </Button>
    )}
/>
```

The register_meta function is

```
function _duib_p_addimages_register_post_meta() {
register_meta(
    'post',
    '_duib_p_addimages',
    [
        'auth_callback' => '__return_true',
        'default'       => __( '', '_duib_p_addimages' ),
        'show_in_rest' => array(
        'schema' => array( 
            'type'  => 'array', 
            'items' => array( 
                'type' => 'string' 
            )
        )
            ),
        'single'        => true,
        'type'          => 'string',
        'object_subtype' => 'properties',
    ]
);
}
add_action( 'init', '_duib_p_addimages_register_post_meta' );
```

The sample json output is

```
"meta": {
 
  "_duib_p_mediaURL": "http://localhost/property/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/hele_03.jpg",
  "_duib_p_description": "",
  "_duib_p_addimages": [
    
  ]
},
```

Comment: I can see that you're trying to save the ID in your blocks attributes, but there is no connection between your blocks attributes and meta that I can see in your question, and you're saving URLs not IDs. It's also very difficult to follow your code as it's only shared in very brief snippets, so I can't tell when and where things happen, and the block attributes are missing. There's also no context to the question, what are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: When I add 'meta: "_duib_p_mediaID",  source: "meta",  default: ""' to an attribute, the data is saved in meta using register_meta function. 

example:   "meta": {
      "_duib_p_heading": "Ipsum porro hic aut",
      "_duib_p_mediaURL": "http://localhost/property/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/115392_sandiego_villastmichele_03.jpg",

What I need is to display a gallery on the same page. The multiple media upload works in Gutenberg editor. I just don't know how to save the url's as array in meta.

Comment: you haven't shared enough of the code to be able to answer this, describing it in words is not enough, and you've still provided no context. Please use the `Edit` link to fix this in your question rather than using comments. You need to provide _significantly_ more code. If you don't then people writing answers won't be able to guide you even if they have a solution. And why save it in meta? That's not how blocks are meant to work, normally post meta is stored and set via sidebar panels and plugins, not blocks

Comment: WordPress has evolved a lot. It started as blogging software. Today it's way more than blogging software/CMS. I wasn't interested in WordPress until Gutenberg was introduced. I am creating things using WordPress functions, I am not hijacking the editor or anything. Just thinking out of the box and creating solutions. I don't intend to offend you in any way.

Comment: My idea is to create a plugin that shows data using a plugin. Basically, I want to create 2 blocks, 1 to add data and another block to display the data. Adding a sidebar makes it theme-dependent. I want the plugin to work even if the theme is changed. I have created 2 plugins with similar ideas and they are approved and live in the WordPress plugin directory. People are using it.

Comment: By sidebar I meant the sidebar in the block editor, not a widget area. By using a block this would appear in the block inspector, rather than as a panel in the post sidebar. Though you can set post meta in a block it's very much frowned upon and in newer versions deprecated to do it via block attributes, you're supposed to modify the meta directly. You also have the problem that meta is tied to a post, not a block. If you need to execute PHP on the frontend and are using post meta to retrieve the data from the block then that's not the way to do it, you can render blocks in PHP with attributes

Comment: which also provides an alternative to your problem that bypasses it, aka composition via multiple blocks, rather than 1 block that contains an array or multiple IDs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141586/discussion-between-mangesh-yadav-and-tom-j-nowell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses very old way of saving data to meta. This (using meta property in attributes) is not recommended anymore.

Instead, use `useEntityProp` hook to save data to meta [(example in handbook)](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/).

In your case, you'll have to construct array from image metadata, where data of each image may be array or object and you save array of images as array of objects or array of arrays. In register_meta you'll have to set 'single' to `false` to facilitate saving array. In useEntityProp I use 'page' as second argument for brevity, but that depents on your post type, or you can use `getCurrentPostType` selector like in handbook example to get current post type and that would work for all.

```
import { useEntityProp } from '@wordpress/core-data';
const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', 'page', 'meta' );

// meta is object where meta data are properties

function saveImageMeta(gallery) {
  // construct your array here 
  // (if I remember correctly, you do get already formed array from MediaUpload, but you may want to remove excessive properties
  // I will use just gallery for brevity

  // add gallery property to existing meta's
  setMeta({...meta, gallery});
}

}
// save like this
return (
  <MediaUpload
    onSelect={(gallery) => {
    saveImageMeta(gallery);
    }}
    type="image"
    multiple
    value={meta['gallery']}
    render={({ open }) => (
    <Button className="button button-large" onClick={open}>
        Select Images
    </Button>
    )}
  />
);
```

However, I think `value={meta['gallery']}` would not work for selecting already chosen images, you'll have to construct correct array, if I am not mistaken. Please try to figure out this yourself.

Do note also that reading this meta's in PHP is a bit more complicated, as it is an array of arrays or array of objects.

Comment: Hey @Lovor ... Thanks for pointing it out. I have already read about the new useEntityProp method. I will update the code to the new method. I have decided to use gallery blocks as additional blocks to the post. This way I don't have to save everything in meta.

Comment: Basically, I am building a property listing plugin just to kill time and upgrade my skills. So far there are 2 blocks. 1st block adds property items to list the basic details of the property. 2nd block is to display the custom post type posts/property items on a page. I was trying to include the additional images of the property and floorplans into the meta but it's not needed. Hence I will use another block named additional property details to add more content to the property page.

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted answer, no matter that you switched to another solution, because it addresses question you asked.